# Are anonymous functions able to handle removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Consider following example. We have a simple html file

```
<body>
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="create_button()">Create button</button>
</body>
```

and two versions of js files. ver. a:

```
function create_button() {
    var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
    new_button.innerHTML = "Pop the alert";
    new_button.type = "button";
    new_button.addEventListener('click', function () { my_function("you") });
    new_button.removeEventListener('click', function () { my_function("you") });
    document.body.appendChild(new_button);
};

function my_function(x) {
    alert("I like " + x);
};
```

and ver. b:

```
function create_button() {
    var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
    new_button.innerHTML = "Pop the alert";
    new_button.type = "button";  
    function helper() {
        my_function("you");
    };
    new_button.addEventListener('click', helper );
    new_button.removeEventListener('click', helper );
    document.body.appendChild(new_button);
};

function my_function(x) {
    alert("I like " + x);
};
```

The former does not work (in fact removeEventListener does not work) and the latter does.

So I ask if there is some problem with anonymous functions or is there some fundamental aspect that prevents first code from executing properly.

Comment: Why add the listener, and then try to immediately remove it? It can never be used if you do that.

Comment: @KevBot This is just a concept question. In practice  I add one with parameter n and remove one with parameter n+1 and removal doesn't act. I used such things in dynamic form.

Comment: To avoid compatibility issue, prefer to use a library like jQuery ;-)

Comment: Consider the fact that because of closures, identical functions aren't necessarily identical in scope, so it would be a serious problem if all similar functions in structure but not in variable scope were removed when trying to remove one. This makes identity very important.

Comment: @squint I'v already few times encountered notion closure, but I treaded it as irrelevant. I believe I need to look into this topic eventually. Thx for motivation.

Comment: You're welcome. It turns out to be a very important concept in JS, and really pretty simple once you've got a handle on it.

Comment: @squint As for the notion itself. Is it related to the closure of some operation somehow? Like adding two natural numbers does not kick us from natural numbers?

Comment: @FallenApart: No, it's entirely a matter of variable scope, where a function keeps a permanent reference to its enclosing scope, even if you pass that function out of the scope. So imagine you have two or more functions that look like this `function foo() { console.log(x); }`. Structurally they would be identical, but if they were created in different scopes where each has its own `x` variable in the enclosing scope, each function may produce a different result when invoked because the `x` variable could have a different value. I'll make a demo in a minute.

Comment: ...[here's a simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r991Lrkh/1/) that shows the idea of closures. As long as the functions that are returned from `makeCounter()` exist, the "closed over" variables within will exist even though the `makeCoutner()` function exited long ago. So that's what's referred to as a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To remove event handlers, the function specified with the addEventListener() method must be an external function,…
>   Anonymous functions, like "element.removeEventListener("event", function(){ myScript });" will not work.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

Note: To those anti-w3schoolers, I knew the answer but couldn't find a proper reference in MDN.

Comment: great!. So the answer is no. Thx a lot. I had probelms with that issue.

Comment: Do you know if there is some logic in that?

Comment: I do not forget such things.

Comment: I believe that if there were more than one `eventListener`, then the method needs to identify the right one somehow.

Comment: You are right. When we consider addEvenListener, we can add the same copy twice and js engine can treat them as different. However in removeEvenListener case, we need to know which one we like to remove. And here we stuck, if we treat each code imput `function () { my_function("you")` as different beeing.

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh on w3school. Due to the fact that it has plenty of users, we can be almost sure that it does not lie. Cause if it does, someone would already notice that and the problem would be fixed.

Comment: IMO w3shools have come a long way. I have found some of their explanations much more comprehensible than MDN's terse explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't use anonymous functions with `removeEventListener`, but it's worth knowing why.

In your first implementation, you're adding an event listener as an anonymous function, then immediately removing an event listener (with the exact same code) right afterward. However, even though the listener functions you added/removed had the same code, they are treated as 2 totally separate functions, because they are. You've defined a function twice, and so even though both function have the same implementation, they have different reference IDs in memory and aren't tied to each other at all.

In your second (working) implementation, you only define a function once, and then *reference* that function both when adding and removing the listener. This means that internally, the JS engine is looking at the same object (functions are also objects) in memory, and so it can remove the original function that was added.

So the problem isn't so much that the function you're using is anonymous, it's that *because* the function is anonymous there's no way to reference it later when you want to remove it, and so you ended up trying to remove a function you created on the fly, which of course won't work because that function was never added to the target element in the first place.

The [MDN docs on removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) may be helpful.

Comment: That makes sense. Thx.